# command cl.exe failed upon pip install django_compressor

Tags: django, visual-studio, python-3.x, pip, cl.exe

im posting this because im encountering this problem and had been trying to solve this issue for days but failed to. I faced the following error (refer to attached) when i try to install django_compressor (pip install django_compressor) i searched online for solutions but is unable to rectify the problem.[figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaV4O.png)

Im currently have python 3.6 with visual studio 14.0 and visual C++ build tools installed. I had referred to ***stackoverflow.com/questions/32740319/error-command-cl-exe-failed-no-such-file-or-directory-python-3-4*** to attempt to try the command "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /E:ON /V:ON /T:0E /K "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.cmd" /RELEASE /x64" from one of the answer posted but i still face problem with x64 compilers not installed.

And i tried to solve the x64 compilers issue by installing the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1 referencing from ***help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/1266-no-64bit-compiler-in-the-71-windows-sdk***

And also uninstalling visual studio service pack 1 to rectify the x64 compilers issue referencing from Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 and Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 Issue in the microsoft visual studio ***https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg697159*** but still to no availability.

Right now i do not know how to proceed on solving the problem of installing django_compressor (cl.exe) as well as the x64 compilers when i try to retify the cl.exe problem. Would require your assistance in this, thank you so much!

**###############################################################################**

**NOTE EDITED: Hi all, i would like to say i manage to find a possible solution, because the program regards to cl.exe with is i presume it got to do with x64 compilers and knowing this issue occur when trying to install rjsmin and rcssmin. I decided to download both the package, extract it and install it using "python setup.py install --without-c-extensions" and it works so i presume it got to do with c extensions and i manage to install django_compressor. But i would like to check will this cause any possible problems in the future? Thank you so much once again!**