# python pip on Windows - command 'cl.exe' failed

Tags: python, windows, pip

I'm trying to install spaCy using `pip install spacy` but I'm getting the following error ..

[image]

I have VS 2015 installed, and I have the following Python install ..

`3.5.2 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]`

I tried the following SO solutions to no avail ..

- [command cl.exe failed upon pip install django_compressor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672714/command-cl-exe-failed-upon-pip-install-django-compressor)
- [error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38059732/error-command-cl-exe-failed-no-such-file-or-directory)

As well as various others. This is not a unique problem to this specific library but more generally anytime I try to install Python libraries that need C to build on Windows.

Comment: i am getting this error when i am trying to install gdal in pycharm . Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You are installing a package with parts written in C/C++, so you need to have `cl.exe` (the Microsoft C Compiler) installed on your computer and in your `PATH`. `PATH` is an environment variable that tells Windows where to find executable files.

First, ensure the **C++ build tools** for Visual Studio are installed.

- If you already have Visual Studio on your computer, install **Desktop development with C++** from the Visual Studio Installer, which you should have in Start Menu.
- Otherwise, you can download **Build Tools for Visual Studio** separately from the [Visual Studio downloads page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) (near the bottom of the page), then choose **C++ build tools** from the installer.

Then, instead of the normal Command Prompt or PowerShell, use one of the special command prompts in the **Visual Studio folder in Start Menu**. This sets up `PATH` automatically, so that `cl.exe` can be found.

- For 32-bit Python, use **x86 Native Tools Command Prompt**.
- For 64-bit Python, use **x64 Native Tools Command Prompt**.

Answer (score 27):

This is easily the simplest solution.
For those who don't know how to do this:

1. Install the C++ compiler
   https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019
2. Go to the installation folder (In my case it is):
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools
3. Open Visual C++ 2015 x86 x64 Cross Build Tools Command Prompt
4. Type: `pip install package_name`

Comment: I tried to follow your instructions but I am getting error `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I am trying to install package `pychm`. While trying to install the package directly in usual command prompt I am getting the error `command cl.exe failed`. Can you please suggest if am doing something wrong. BTW I am working on python 3.6 and windows 7.

Comment: That means python.exe isn't in your environment variables list. You will need to give its full location, i.e. (In my case):
"C:\Program Files\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\Scripts\pip.exe" install package_name

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: You've got the link for 2019 edition here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16

Comment: to add to @KunalMathur comment, if you use a conda environment, your pip executable may be found in a folder such as `C:\Users\<username>\miniconda3\envs\subdivnet\Scripts\pip.exe`. Just run `where pip` from within your conda environment to find the path.

Comment: This worked for me! whereas doing pip install in Git Bash did not work-- somehow some *.h files were in a directory that was not searched when building the wheel. Why might it have worked in the Visual C++ command prompt but not in Git Bash or another shell?

Answer (score 13):

In my case I need to install more tools from Visual Studio (I'm using VS 2017 Community and Python 3.6.4). I installed those tools (see installer screenshot [here](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/03/incredibuild.png)):

1. **Desktop development with C++:** I included all defaulted items and the next ones:

   - Windows XP support for C++
   - Support for C++/CLI
   - VC++ 2015.3 v140 toolset
2. **Linux development with C++**

Then I opened the **Windows PowerShell** as *Administrator privilegies* (Right click to open) and move folder of Visual Studio installation and find that path:

```
cd [Visual Studio Path]\VC\Auxiliary\Build
```

Then I executed this file:

```
.\vcvars32.bat
```

After that I use pip as normal, for instance, I wanted to install *Mayavi*:

```
pip install mayavi
```

I hope that it helps someone too.

Comment: For what it's worth - I was getting the same error trying to install psycopg2-binary, and just reconfiguring VS 2017 Community as you suggested fixed this for me (didn't need to add anything to my path, etc.)

Comment: In case anyone can't find the Auxiliary folder, I didn't have one, look in the Bin folder. The bat file is there.

Answer (score 5):

Refer to this link:

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cytoolz

Download the right whl package for you python version(if you have trouble knowing what version of python you have, just lunch the interpreter )

use pip to install the package, assuming that the file is in downloads folder and you have python 3.6 32 bit :

python -m pip install C:\Users\%USER%\Downloads\cytoolz‑0.9.0.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl

this is not valid for just this package, but for any package that cannot compile under your own windows installation.

Answer (score 4):

Just added to the answer from Kunal Mathur and an answer to @mockash, since I cannot comment due to lack of reputation.

Before you type: pip install package_name, you need to change the directory to the folder where pip.exe is. for example:

> Open Visual C++ 2015 x86 x64 Cross Build Tools Command Prompt-->
>   change directory cd
>   C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts-->Type:
>   pip install package_name

But the weird thing is I can only successfully install via `'Visual C++ 2015 x64 x86' not 'x86 x64'`

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem with visual studio 2017.

you can find cl.exe in
`C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx86\x86`.

just set the environment variable as the able address and run the command in anaconda, it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it really easy and a joy to automate, check out Chocolatey.org/install and you can basically copy and paste these commands and tweak it based on what versions of VC++ you need.

This command is taken from https://chocolatey.org/install

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

Once you have chocolatey installed you can either close and reopen your Powershell terminal or run this command:

```
Import-Module "$env:ChocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1" ; Update-SessionEnvironment
```

Now you can use Chocolatey to install Python (latest version of 3.x is default).

```
choco install python

# This next command installs the latest VisualStudio installer that lets you get specific versions of the build
# Microsoft has replaced the 2015 and 2017 installer links with this one, and we can still use it to install the 2015 and 2017 components

choco install visualstudio2019buildtools --package-parameters "--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.140 --passive --locale en-US --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.$($PSVersionTable.BuildVersion.Build) --no-includeRecommended" -y --timeout 0

# Usually need the "unlimited" timeout aka "0" because Visual Studio Installer takes forever

# Tool portion
# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools
# Component portion(s)
# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.140
# Win10SDK needs to match your current Win10 build version
# $($PSVersionTable.BuildVersion.Build)
# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.$($PSVersionTable.BuildVersion.Build)

# Because VS2019 Build Tools are dumb, need to manually link a couple files between the SDK and the VC++ dirs
# You may need to tweak the version here, but it has been updated to be as dynamic as possible 
# Use an elevated Powershell or elevated cmd prompt (if using cmd.exe just use the bits after /c)
cmd /c mklink "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\rc.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\$($PSVersionTable.BuildVersion.Major).$($PSVersionTable.BuildVersion.Minor).$($PSVersionTable.BuildVersion.Build).0\x64\rc.exe"

cmd /c mklink "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\rcdll.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\$($PSVersionTable.BuildVersion.Major).$($PSVersionTable.BuildVersion.Minor).$($PSVersionTable.BuildVersion.Build).0\x64\rcdll.dll"
```

Once you have this installed, you should reboot. I've occasionally had things work without a reboot, but your `pip install` commands will work best if you reboot first.

Now you can `pip install pipenv` or `pip install complex-package` and should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I had come across this problem many times. There is `cl.exe` but for some strange reason `pip` couldn't find it, even if we run the command from the `bin` folder where `cl.exe` is present. Try using conda installer, it worked fine for me.

As you can see in the following image, `pip` is not able to find the `cl.exe`. Then I tried installing using conda

[image: image 1]

And to my surprise it gets installed without an error once you have the right version of vs cpp build tools installed, i.e. v14.0 in the right directory.

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Microsoft visual c++ 14.0 build tool.(Windows 7)
2. create a virtual environment using conda.
3. Activate the environment and use conda to install the necessary package.

For example:
conda install -c conda-forge spacy