# Installing SciKit-Image Error 127

Tags: python

Hi I have been having  trouble  trying to install SciKit-Image for a long  time  now. I have installed all of the dependencies and upgraded all of them. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what happens when I attempt installation through pip

```
error: Command "cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\python\include -Ic:\python\include /Tcskimage\_shared\geometry.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\skimage\_shared\geometry.obj" failed with exit status 127



Command "c:\python\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\iankr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-lba2niop\\scikit-image\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\iankr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-k16oa42b-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\iankr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-lba2niop\scikit-image\
```

And Here is what happened with Easy Install

```
error: Setup script exited with error: Command "cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\python\include -Ic:\python\include /Tcskimage\_shared\geometry.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\skimage\_shared\geometry.obj" failed with exit status 127
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a C compiler for the native code of that package. You can get for Python 2.7 from Microsoft:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

A complete list for other versions of Python is available here:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: I have installed the Visual C++ 14, which the website says is recommended for Python 3.6. I am still getting the same error, did I need to do anything with the file after installed and run? Thanks for your sugestion.

Comment: I dont know how to setup the compiler. I have installed and run it, but do not know where the setup file is, and there does not seem to be in any help on it. Do you have any more ideas?

Comment: Maybe one of these will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724445/python-pip-on-windows-command-cl-exe-failed