# Fail downloading cx_Freeze

Tags: python

I am getting this error trying to download `cx_Freeze`.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\BregmanM\Downloads\cx_Freeze-5.0.2>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing cx_Freeze.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to cx_Freeze.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to cx_Freeze.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'cx_Freeze.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.txt'
writing manifest file 'cx_Freeze.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'cx_Freeze.util' extension
cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\BregmanM\AppData\Local\Pro
grams\Python\Python36-32\include -IC:\Users\BregmanM\AppData\Local\Programs\Pyth
on\Python36-32\include /Tcsource/util.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\source/u
til.obj
error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
```

But the problem here is I tied to fix the `PATH` issue and that did not work for me ([python pip on Windows - command 'cl.exe' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724445/python-pip-on-windows-command-cl-exe-failed)). I also must note, that I cannot just download using `pip install` because I am on a work computer that blocks me from doing so. My only option is to download the `whl` or `tar.gz` file. How can I go about fixing this? I am running on Python 3.6 so using `py2exe` will not work.

---

When I tried adding to PATH this is what I get:

```
cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\BregmanM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\include -IC:\Users\BregmanM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\include /Tcsource/util.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\source/util.obj
error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
```

---

Here is what my directory looks like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe
```

I also have another 6 folders than contain `cl.exe`, but I'm assuming they are different. I even tried adding those to PATH but I get more errors.

Comment: It looks like it cannot find the cl.exe file as it is trying to build the module. You linked another stackoverflow question, did you try adding the cl.exe to your PATH variable like it suggested? Do you even see a cl.exe file anywhere on you computer?

Comment: Just edited my post @stephen

Comment: hmm... I am seeing if I can recreate at all, but everything seems to just work currently. But, what if you download the .whl file and then run `python -m pip install C:/some-dir/cx_Freeze-5.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl` from the command line, does that help at all? If not, it seems to be pointing directly to it just cannot find the cl.exe for whatever reason. Make sure you have the full path to the directory hosting the cl.exe file. In your case that would be C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\ you can check all your path variables by simply typing PATH in cmd