# Unable to install python-Levenshtein on Windows, error code 1

Tags: python, pip

When trying to install python-Levenshtein for a project I'm doing, I'm encountering this error, all the info I've tried to find about it seems to be for other problems that I'm not encountering involving visual studio and other resources that I do not have installed or use for the project.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\user1>pip install python-Levenshtein
Collecting python-Levenshtein
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/42/a9/d1785c85ebf9b7dfacd
08938dd028209c34a0ea3b1bcdb895208bd40a67d/python-Levenshtein-0.12.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\user1\appdata\local\program
s\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from python-Levenshtein) (39.0.1)
Installing collected packages: python-Levenshtein
  Running setup.py install for python-Levenshtein ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\user1\appdata\local\programs\python\pyt
hon37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\user1
\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fgsrabne\\python-Levenshtein\\setup.py';f=ge
tattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.cl
ose();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\user1\AppD
ata\Local\Temp\pip-record-20u1vm40\install-record.txt --single-version-externall
y-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Levenshtein
    copying Levenshtein\StringMatcher.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Levenshtein
    copying Levenshtein\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Levenshtein
    running egg_info
    writing python_Levenshtein.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\dependency_links.txt

    writing entry points to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing namespace_packages to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\namespace_packages
.txt
    writing requirements to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'python_Levenshtein.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*pyc' found anywhere in dist
ribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*so' found anywhere in distr
ibution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.project' found anywhere in
distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.pydevproject' found anywher
e in distribution
    writing manifest file 'python_Levenshtein.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying Levenshtein\_levenshtein.c -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Levenshtein
    copying Levenshtein\_levenshtein.h -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Levenshtein
    running build_ext
    building 'Levenshtein._levenshtein' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\Levenshtein
    cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\user1\appdata\local\pro
grams\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\user1\appdata\local\programs\python\p
ython37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.
0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" "-I
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program
 Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86
)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /TcLevenshtein/_levenshtein.c /Fobuild
\temp.win32-3.7\Release\Levenshtein/_levenshtein.obj
    error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\user1\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -
c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\
pip-install-fgsrabne\\python-Levenshtein\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',
open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code,
 __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-recor
d-20u1vm40\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" fai
led with error code 1 in C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fgsrabne\p
ython-Levenshtein\
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pip on Windows - command 'cl.exe' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724445/python-pip-on-windows-command-cl-exe-failed)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe installing for anaconda can help:

```
pip install conda
conda install -c conda-forge python-levenshtein
```

Comment: this command indeed worked for me (using Windows, Python 3.7), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Anaconda, open the Anaconda prompt and then:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-levenshtein
```

It works for me in this situation.