# Error installing mysqlclient using pycharm

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, cmd

I get an error when I try to connect MySql database using pycharm or even cmd 
I downloaded visual studio 2017 but the problem is still there 
and I tried with cmd all the possible wheels but it says 'this wheel is not supported in this platform'

This is the error I get when I try to install mysqlclient using pycharm[image]

Comment: make sure you'd setted the `project interpreter` correctly

Comment: Are you using a virtual env and did you install mysqlclient in the env? Do you see mysqlclient in project interpreter as per Jimmy above?

Comment: I am using virtual env but how to install mysqlclient in it? @DaveStSomeWhere

Comment: Just download a precompiled package, it is much easier: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient

Comment: I did but still have the same problem it says "this wheel is not supported in this platform" @Selcuk

Comment: Did you install pip in your virtual env? try pip --version and/or pip3 --version

Comment: it says error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory @DaveStSomeWhere

Comment: yes, pip is installed version 19.0.1 @DaveStSomeWhere

Comment: This is a windows thing - this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724445/python-pip-on-windows-command-cl-exe-failed