# How do I install PyAudio on Python 3.7?

Tags: python, pyaudio, cl.exe

I am currently trying to install PyAudio on Python 3.7 but when I use the command ***"pip install pyaudio***", an error message appears:

```
  "command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory".
```

I have already tried to modify the PATH but it doesn't work. I thought maybe someone could help me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Download the wheel on this site [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio).

Choose `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl` if you use 32 bit, or `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` for 64 bit.
Then go to your download folder:

```
cd <your_donwload_path>
```

Then, for 64 bit:

```
pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
```

or for 32 bit:

```
pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl
```

Comment: May you use 32 bit python? If then, you need to download 32 bit version of PyAudio.

Comment: It just gives me the error: "ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform." FYI - I am on a mac

Comment: @DarrowHartman, it's just for windows. It's stated on the page title: Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages.

Comment: @Hiadore, I get this error: ```ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.``` on windows after following your suggested steps. Any hints as to why this is happening?

Comment: My machine and python version 3.7 is 64 bit, but the 64 bit .whl file didn't work

Comment: @ShreyTripathi and DivyanshuKushwaha, can you show me the error message?

Comment: It says `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Python\\Python38\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl'` (((

Answer (score 12):

**WINDOWS**

1. `pip install pipwin`
2. `pipwin install pyaudio`

This will install pyaudio

Answer (score 3):

It is supported in Python 3.7. Even though not officially on standalone 3.7, Anaconda 2019.10 which uses 3.7 has it.
So you have 2 options:

1. You can `conda install -c anaconda pyaudio`, if you use Anaconda
2. Or for standalone Python 3.7 you can:

**2a)**
After installing the .whl, build portaudio.dll just following the instructions at http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_windows.html. I used VS2019 and i worked.
Note if you choose ASIO option you will need ASIO SDK from https://www.steinberg.net/en/company/developers.html

After that just put portaudio.dll anywhere in your system path or local directory and you can `import pyaudio`.

**2b)** If you don't want to build, simply steal portaudio.dll from Anaconda. It's in `<Anaconda_root>/Library/bin`

Answer (score 2):

It's not compatible with 3.7 and as far as I have been able to find thus far there doesn't appear to be any work being put into making it compatible and I haven't found any sort of replacement, so unless you want to build the package yourself and make it compatible with 3.7 then it can't be used without downgrading your python install to 3.6, I did try Hiadore's answer and that does not work either with 3.7.

Answer (score 2):

Simply Download wheel file from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio , get the file for your Python version and bitness. Change the directory location to the download file location or copy downloaded file to the working location.

Install it with pip install filename.whl

Answer (score 1):

Extract to https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

In **Windows**:

Install using pip:

```
python -m pip install pyaudio
```

Currently, there are wheels compatible with the official distributions of **Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6.**

Apparently there is no version of that library for Python 3.7, so I'd try downgrading the Python version.

If you continue to have problems with the error of .exe, in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41724634/7290770 they solve it.

Answer (score 1):

pyaudio is not supported with python 3.7.

Downgrade your version to python 3.6.8.

then try installing pyaudio using the command: pip install pyaudio

Answer (score 1):

1. Install python 3.6
2. Install PyCharm
3. While in PyCharm click File
4. Click on settings
5. Click Project Interpreter
6. Click on the Gear icon ,You should see Add,Show All
   Click on Add
7. Next Click System Interpreter
8. Click the dropdown if you installed python 3.6 you should see it there
9. Click it Hit ok and install PyAudio this should fix it..

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) link  to download `.whl` file according to the python version it supports.
For Python -3.7 use PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl

Go and run this command on the Windows command prompt:

```
pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
```

Comment: This answer is correct one +1, wonder why it got downvoted. Thanks!