# when i try to install pyaudio it gives me this huge error

Tags: python, pyaudio

I wrote a assistant and it says:
please build and install the portaudio python bindings first
And when i want to install pyaudio  it gives a huge error message

```
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\degin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\degin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zos6mmry\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\degin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3d78nl9h\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
ERROR: running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.7
copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
running build_ext
building '_portaudio' extension
creating build\temp.win32-3.7
creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\degin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\degin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
_portaudiomodule.c
src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
----------------------------------------
 ERROR: Command "'c:\users\degin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\degin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zos6mmry\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\degin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3d78nl9h\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\degin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zos6mmry\pyaudio\
```

My assistant start to work, it says only one line of conversation and the exits with this:
   And when i want to install pyaudio  it gives a huge error message

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54998028/how-do-i-install-pyaudio-on-python-3-7

Comment: i did it what the post say'd and i got this message:WARNING: Requirement 'PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: Are you using a 32 or 64 bit computer?

Comment: Im using 64 bit computer

Comment: I'm not sure it should work maybe pip or pip3 perhaps downgrade to python 3.6? I'm not to sure

Comment: i reinstalled the whole python and my assisstant works fine i thank your for your time and have a nice day! :)