# Pip install pyaudio not working on windows also tried with vs

Tags: python, pyaudio

Trying to install **PyAudio** using command `pip install pyaudio`
but failed with the following error message:

```
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
    Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\aryat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aryat\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wz3bueat\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aryat\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wz3bueat\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aryat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-o91_9x1y\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\aryat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\PyAudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\aryat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wz3bueat\PyAudio\
    Complete output (13 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src
    cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\aryat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\aryat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\aryat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aryat\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wz3bueat\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aryat\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wz3bueat\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aryat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-o91_9x1y\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\aryat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\PyAudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio    download from here and install with pip

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pip on Windows - command 'cl.exe' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724445/python-pip-on-windows-command-cl-exe-failed)

Answer (score 1):

Download [Microsoft Build Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48159) if you haven't yet.

The error says that `cl.exe is not found`. If you have it installed , go to programs and features and repair the tools.
For more refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54998028/how-do-i-install-pyaudio-on-python-3-7).

Answer (score 0):

Source: [python pip on Windows - command 'cl.exe' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724445/python-pip-on-windows-command-cl-exe-failed)

You need to have `cl.exe` (the Microsoft C Compiler) installed on your computer and in your `PATH`. `PATH` is an environment variable that tells Windows where to find executable files.

First, ensure the **C++ build tools** for Visual Studio are installed. You can download **Build Tools for Visual Studio** separately from the [Visual Studio downloads page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/), then choose **C++ build tools** from the installer. If you already have Visual Studio, you can also install **Desktop development with C++** from the Visual Studio Installer which you should have in Start Menu.

Then, instead of the normal Command Prompt or PowerShell, use one of the special command prompts in the **Visual Studio folder in Start Menu**. For 32-bit Python, you're probably looking for **x86 Native Tools Command Prompt**. This sets up `PATH` automatically, so that `cl.exe` can be found.