# Python pip on WIndows - command error "cl.exe"

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, pyaudio, cl.exe

I am trying to install PyAudio using `pip install PyAudio`, but I get this error:

```
(venv) C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\untitled>pip install PyAudio
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-
0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
  Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;_
_file__='C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z9jx52y1\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__)
;code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\T
emp\pip-record-dzl_covu\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\PC\PycharmProj
ects\untitled\venv\include\site\python3.7\PyAudio:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
    cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -IC:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\include -IC:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Pro
grams\Python\Python37-32\include -IC:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
 Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)
\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Fi
les (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.o
bj
    error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\PC\\
AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z9jx52y1\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('
\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dzl_covu\
install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\inclu
de\site\python3.7\PyAudio" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z9jx52y1\PyAudio\
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I also tried using `pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`, but I got the same problem...

Comment: Have you checked other answers here? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41724634/11145532

Comment: Where can I get  the "cl.exe" file

Answer (score 0):

Run your command prompt as administrator and add Full path of **cl.exe** to **Path** environment variable.

Comment: Where can I get  the "cl.exe" file