# why do I keep getting this error during web3py module installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, bitarray, web3py

I'm trying to install web3 module for python and I keep getting that is connected to bitarray. hare's the error I keep getting:

```
error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\l\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\l\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6nq49h42\\bitarray_762632bbfc03447084c19315d24278db\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\l\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6nq49h42\\bitarray_762632bbfc03447084c19315d24278db\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\l\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-2_4t1ncs\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
--install-headers 'c:\users\l\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\bitarray'                   
         cwd: C:\Users\l\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6nq49h42\bitarray_762632bbfc03447084c19315d24278db\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build  
    running build_py      
    creating build                
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9       
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray                          
    copying bitarray\test_bitarray.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray                                                                                                                                                
    copying bitarray\test_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
    copying bitarray\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray  
    copying bitarray\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bitarray
    running build_ext                                                     
    building 'bitarray._bitarray' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9                                    
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release                    
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\bitarray                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\l\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\l\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include /Tcbitarray/_bitarray.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\bitarray/_bitarray.obj
    error: command 'cl.exe' failed: None  
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\l\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\l\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6nq49h42\\bitarray_762632bbfc03447084c19315d24278db\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\l\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6nq49h42\\bitarray_762632bbfc03447084c19315d24278db\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\l\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-2_4t1ncs\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\l\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\bitarray' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: It seems like bitarray is written in C. Try setting up the environment accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724445/python-pip-on-windows-command-cl-exe-failed/41724634

Comment: @JakobSchödl when I launch x64 Native Tools Command Prompt it closes immediately.