# Guys i. Am getting this error while trying to install slither Can anybody tell me the reason of this error and how can i fix this

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2 [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp Failed to build aiohttp

i tried updating pip but it still doesnt work

Comment: Try [these ideas for getting compilation working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724445/python-pip-on-windows-command-cl-exe-failed) with Visual Studio 14 from Pip.